# VMWare iso image if can be transferred to my macbook pro free space partition?

Tags: disk-utility, partition, unix

Even though I have been a member for a long time, I am a newbie on the Ubuntu command line or the logic behind it.  I am asking this forum because a lot of you are already above average or experts in analyzing issues and providing workarounds since you know the ins and outs of the Ubuntu or Linux operating system.  I am in no way trying to get a Linux certification, I only want to install a working Ubuntu system in order for me to install the program that I need in the first place.

So as an overview:
I have roughly 500GB SSD HDD on my Macbook Pro laptop.  I used disk utility to shrink the Mac HD partition to 400GB.  So now I have 100 GB to install my Ubuntu Server OS.

If it's a straightforward clean install of an Ubuntu Server, I have done that and made it work side by side with MacOS.  What I want is to use an Ubuntu ISO image with preconfigured programs inside of it.  There is an ISO image available for that, so I would like to know if what I am going to do below is the logical way of making this work?

1. I used disk utility to shrink the Mac HD partition to from 500GB to 400GB.  So now I have 100 GB to install my Ubuntu Server preconfigured ISO image.
2. Download the Ubuntu ISO image with preconfigured programs and applications to a USB pen/thumb drive (minimum size of 2GB).
3. Use Unetbootin and select that ISO image and make the USB pen/thumb drive bootable.
4. Install reFind in order to have a boot manager to choose to boot in MacOS or Linux environment.  Naturally, I will choose Linux or Debian environment.
5. This will then go to the usual setup menu of Ubuntu, or will I be encountering a different set of menu options?  What do I need to choose then?
6. If the preconfigured ISO Ubuntu image was created with a 25Gb of HD space.  What commands or what steps do I need to fulfill in order to expand the 25GB to occupy the whole 100GB that I partitioned in step 1?

I read the procedure on this link:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions

Does this mean when I use gparted, it will then detect the 75GB free space and would let me merge it with the 25GB space the pre-configured Ubuntu image is occupying?

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Please add a link to the *...Ubuntu ISO image with preconfigured programs inside of it. There is an ISO image available for that,...*!

Comment: it's an iso image that I can extract in vmware or virtual box.  Do you need it?

https://docs.gns3.com/1QXVIihk7dsOL7Xr7Bmz4zRzTsJ02wklfImGuHwTlaA4/index.html

Comment: I had the impression that it is an iso image available in the public. Is the iso a specialized/custom Ubuntu server installer (e.g only installing the Ubuntu base system, a hypervisor and some vm-server/vm-client config tools) or does the iso contain an image of an already installed and partly configured server made with e.g. `dd`?

Comment: Hi, yes it's available to the public.  It's an Ubuntu server image that was installed inside VMWare or ESXi.  From there, the tools and applications were installed.  I believe you can then export this image as an ISO image.  So my question is that can I use that ISO to be transferred to a different hardware platform like a Macbook Pro laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu image requires a different file system. VMware usage is different than Bootcamp. As you've had success installing Ubuntu server to work side by side with Mac OS, I'd suggest you built on top of that. You could safely replace the working Ubuntu install with an alternative install. You may find that many drivers are missing or disabled though, as the VMware version was counting on different hardware than your MBP. Your full Ubuntu install took the hardware into account.

If you really want to use this pre-configured VMware version, you might want to consider running it in VMware. Sorry to be a party pooper with this advice, but I hate to see anyone looking at as many hours of installation work with such slim possibilities of getting a truly usable result.

On the plus side, if you can at least boot and get graphics with the ISO version, you may be able to run a reconfiguration script to optimise the install for your hardware.

Comment: Hi,  yes understand where you are coming from.  I'll follow your advice.